# Use independent scanner and printer as one (specifically for photocopy)

Tags: macos, printing, scanning

I have a Canon Lide 110 (scanner) and an Epson L120 (printer) which I want to combine to achieve the feature set of an off the shelf all-in-one printer-scanner. Is there a software that I can use to do this on my MacBook Pro?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it‘s not about Apple products or their use.

Comment: Isn't it on topic when I'm asking for a software or a solution that will let me do this within macOS? If not by community standards, then I'm confused. 

Comment: Now that you edited the question to indicate that you are using a Mac it is on-topic. Nevertheless please have a look at https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation to see what is expected of questions asking about software recommendation.

Comment: Most scanning software that I have seen has an option of where to send the scanned document, email, photos.app, dropbox, etc. Often one of the "destinations" is "Print." Doing that automatically may depend on that software being AppleScriptable so it triggers the print function when a scan is completed. Failing that you may need to look into alternate scanning software

Comment: https://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/html/vuesc6.htm  explains how to turn a scanner and printer into a photocopier.  There is a free version for testing.  Getting rid of the watermarks costs.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks! I'll be more explicit the next time. 

Comment: @SteveChambers I see. The use of Apple Scripts is too advance for me.

Comment: @historystamp Cool! Will try out VueScan. Thanks! 

Answer (score 1):

You can import an image from a scanner and print it in Preview, though this is not completely scriptable, but will only take a few clicks.

[PDF Pen](https://smilesoftware.com/pdfpen-family) can import from a Scanner and Print the results, and is fully AppleScriptable.

Comment: Yeah. I hope Apple adds Shortcuts to the Mac and there will be a way to create a workflow for this. :)